# Powershell Scripts for AWS EC2 Multiaccounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, powershell, boto3, aws-powershell

I have been looking for an example powershell script which would iterate through multiple accounts in AWS and just print EC2 instance info from every account. I have been using Python/Boto3 to accomplish the same task , but want to learn Powershell way of doing this. I have searched but couldn't find any example of multi account especially as how to get sts token for every account and assume role etc. If anyone could please point me to any such example script if available, that would be great.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It might be helpful https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=856626 . This is with powershell module though.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuuming that you would need different credentials for each account.  For each account, you would need to create an AWS credential.  For an example of how to do this see: https://timharkin.com/managing-aws-credentials-with-powershell/

Once you have the credentials saved, you can use three nested loops to get the info you are looking for.  Those loops would be Credential->Region-->EC2 Instance. The code for this would be:

```
$AccountCreds = "Credential1","Credential2"
$Regions="ap-northeast-1","ap-northeast-2","ap-south-1","ap-southeast-1","ap-southeast-2","ca-central-1","eu-central-1","eu-north-1","eu-west-1","eu-west-2","eu-west-3","sa-east-1","us-east-1","us-east-2","us-west-1","us-west-2"

foreach ($credential in $AccountCreds){
    Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName $credential

    foreach($region in $Regions){

        Set-DefaultAWSRegion $region
        try {

            (Get-EC2Instance  ).Instances |Format-Table  -AutoSize | Out-String  -Width 512

        }
        catch {

        }

    }
}
```